# How to handle index out of range in JSON ( Go)

Tags: json, go

I'm developing a web service and part of that I read the Request.Body and try to unmarshal it.

```
if err := json.NewDecoder(body).Decode(r); err !=nil{
    log.Error(err)
    return err
}
```

The issue is that sometimes the client is sending an empty body and I get a panic `runtime error: index out of range
goroutine 7 [running]:`
 How am I supposed to mitigate this?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue, but I can't get the `index out of range` error. The `Decode` simply returns an empty string when it reaches `EOF`. Is this error comming from inside the json package or your own code? Also from your example - the error might be `io.EOF`, which will be returned when the stream ends. You could also look inside your UnmarshalJSON method for the source of the error?

Comment: The errors comes out of the json package. `body` is simply the `Request.Body` field of the http request. The easiest way to reproduce is to read the request body on a GET request.

Comment: What version of go are you using? Could [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3450) be your problem? When I try your example I get an empty struct and nothing's panicing. I'm probably at fault here, so sorry for not being able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am decomposing your code:

[NewDecoder](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewDecoder): -

```
func NewDecoder(r io.Reader) *Decoder
```

> NewDecoder returns a new decoder that reads from r. The decoder
>   introduces its own buffering and may read data from r beyond the JSON
>   values requested.

So NewDecoder only reads data from `r`. it's not care, is `r` empty...

[Decode](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode):-

```
func (dec *Decoder) Decode(v interface{}) error
```

> Decode reads the next JSON-encoded value from its input and stores it
>   in the value pointed to by v.
>
> See the documentation for Unmarshal for details about the conversion of JSON into a Go value.

To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:

```
bool, for JSON booleans
float64, for JSON numbers
string, for JSON strings
[]interface{}, for JSON arrays
map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
nil for JSON null
```

> If a JSON value is not appropriate for a given target type, or if a
>   JSON number overflows the target type, Unmarshal skips that field and
>   completes the unmarshalling as best it can. If no more serious errors
>   are encountered, Unmarshal returns an UnmarshalTypeError describing
>   the earliest such error.
>
> The JSON null value unmarshals into an interface, map, pointer, or
>   slice by setting that Go value to nil. Because null is often used in
>   JSON to mean “not present,” unmarshaling a JSON null into any other Go
>   type has no effect on the value and produces no error.

Reading above statement, it's clear that there is not chances, we get run time panic error. I was experimenting with a [sample code](http://play.golang.org/p/u3o8iAYwGG) to reproduce this ERROR. May error coming from inside the JSON package or your own code.

Answer (score -1):

```
var dummy []byte
dummy = make([]byte, 10)
size, _ := body.Read(dummy)
if size > 0 {
  if err := json.NewDecoder(body).Decode(r); err != nil {
          log.Error(err)
          return err
} 
fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", "Json cannot be empty")// where w is http.ResponseWriter
```

Comment: **Never** ignore returned `error` values! Idiomatic is to combine the first lines into `dummy := make([]byte, 10)`. But then you proceed to chuck those read bytes giving no reasonable hope of JSON decoding ever working! (Were you perhaps thinking of using an `io.MultiReader` to combine dummy+body? If so, you could instead wrap `req.Body` in a `bufio.Reader` and use [`Peek`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.Peek).)